# String as key being converted into symbol giving different behavior in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to utilize a function, generate_csv_for_x, that is already written. One of the parameters is a sort, which should be a hash, i.e. `{:on => "date", :direction => "desc"}`.

This code eventually calls `apply_sort`. Relevant code below.

```
on, direction = sort.values_at "on", "direction"

      if on == "date"
        order_on = "x.created_at"
        return x_scope.order(order_on => direction)
      end

      raise ArgumentError, "Not a valid sort.on value, you passed the following sort: #{sort}"
    end
```

The problem is that "on" and "direction" are not catching their symbol equivalent. Expected behavior. From Rails console I can get this to work just fine, since I just pass a hash with strings as keys.

However, when I call this method from elsewhere, and pass in a hash with strings as keys, they're being automatically converted into symbols. I even tried creating a default value, with strings as keys in this exact file, but they're being converted into symbols.

I can't change the current `on, direction = sort.values_at "on", "direction"` since it breaks a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of any reason why the string keys would be "automatically" converted to symbols - probably there's some code in your application which does this. However you can deal with it pretty easily

for example you can use [Hash#with_indifferent_access](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

```
# this will work even with symbol keys
on, direction = sort.with_indifferent_access.values_at "on", "direction"
```

Or you can use [Hash#stringify_keys](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/stringify_keys) (there's also [Hash#symbolize_keys](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys) for what it's worth, although you wouldn't need that here.)

```
on, direction = sort.stringify_keys.values_at "on", "direction"
```

If you were using plain Ruby (not Rails) and didn't want to include ActiveSupport (which provides `with_indifferent_access` and `stringify_keys`), there are options as well:

You could use [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) which used to be Rails-only, but is in Ruby core since 2.5:

```
on, direction = sort.transform_keys(&:to_s).values_at "on", "direction"
```

Or [each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) / [reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

Answer (score 1):

`values_at` picks values for certain keys from a Hash.

Your Hash `sort` does, according to your posting, not have a key `"on"`. It just has a key `:on`. You could do a

```
on, direction = sort.values_at :on, :direction
```